# show data in multiple textbox in php

Tags: php, html

I want to show all the names of my tb_app which is currently have (4)names stored and show it on my textboxes...can anyone help me make my code work? I'm just a beginner at programming.

current code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include('include/connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT name FROM tb_app";
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $name = $rows['name'];
}
?>
Name List: <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name[0] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name[1] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name[2] ?>" /> <br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name[3] ?>" /> <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are overwriting the `$name` variable in each iteration of your loop. You want to treat `$name` as an array instead, and add an element to the array in each iteration.

Change this:

```
$name = $rows['name'];
```

To this:

```
$name[] = $rows['name'];
```

You could of course echo your textbox directly inside your `while` loop as well, and skip the `$name` variable. However it's good practice to separate your DB or business logic from your display logic, which you are (somewhat) doing. In fact I'd recommend moving your PHP code to the very top of the page, before your opening `<html>` tag even, and limit how much PHP you mix in with your html.

Answer (score 0):

A more dynamic way (i.e you have less or more then 4 names):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
Name List: <br />
   <?php
       include('include/connect.php');
       $sql = "SELECT name FROM tb_app";

       while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
           echo '<input type="text" value="'. $rows['name'] .'" /> <br />';
       }
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go even further:

Change `name` to `names`:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $names[] = $rows['name'];
}
```

And then

Name List:

```
<?php foreach ($names as $name): ?>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $name ?>" /> <br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```